# logs php error but not display it in browser

Tags: php, error-handling

i want to create the error logs but not to display it in browser.

Currently when an error or warning/notice is occurs, then logs is created and error is displayed to the browser but i want to force the system to not show the error message in browser to the site visitor but create the logs for me.

Thanks

Comment: You need this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: to using the ini_set('display_errors','Off'); method will do it.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have something like this in your php.ini:

```
display_errors = Off
error_log = /var/log/php/error.log # Assuming you have /var/log/php directory and it's writable by httpd
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Or set them as run-time options with `ini_set()`

Comment: I uses `ini_set()` but still cannot logs the errors without showing it on browser. I also cannot log the error to other custom file

Answer (score 6):

Add this to the top of your script:

```
//don't display errors
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
//write errors to log
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
//error log file name
ini_set('log_errors', '/var/log/php/error.log');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want log custom errors:

```
try {
    // your code here
} catch (Exception $e){
    error_log($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e->getFile().' Line '.$e->getLine());
}
```

else use [user4035 way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16184920/1559720).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for how to do this in 2023 onwards, this is a quick note to say that all the `ini_set()` answers will only work in runtime from the time they are executed onwards.

This means that errors generated during file parse may still be sent to the browser, and of course those are probably the most common errors.

The usual fix for this varies widely depending on your version of PHP and how it is called; but it's always a variation of a file containing php settings; for instance, a  `php.ini`.  You could add this fragment to such a `php.ini` file:

```
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
```

This would suppress browser errors while enabling logging to  a file.  You may also need to add the line `error_log = error_log`