# Disable PHP errors from displaying on the client?

Tags: php, error-handling, codeigniter-2

I understand this has been asked a bunch of times and probably appropriately answered so I ask you give me some grace here.  I want to log errors to the error log but NOT display them to the client and for some reason nothing I've tried is making any difference.  I'm currently using `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);` and my PHP.ini has the following for `display_errors`:

```
display_errors = Off
```

I thought maybe the framework I'm using or some code was overwriting that value (possibly via `ini_set()`) but if I ask PHP what the value is via:

```
$display_errors = ini_get('display_errors');
if ( filter_var( $display_errors, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) ){
    echo "display_errors = true\n";
} else {
    echo "display_errors = false\n";
}
```

I get `false` (Note: I put the code at the end of the view/template for the framework).  If I `grep` or use VSCode to search the codebase for `display_errors` I don't see any references that override the default behavior.  If it makes any difference the actual value of `display_errors` as reported by `ini_get()` is an empty string `''`.  In case it's not clear this is in the context of Apache2 (Apache/2.4.29) on Ubuntu.  What am I missing?  Is there a third flag around displaying errors? TIA

Edited:
Framework is CodeIgniter v2.2.6 as reported by system/core/CodeIgniter.php.
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.13.
Apache2 (Apache/2.4.29)

Comment: You mention a framework, pleae tell us which one, it could be relevant

Comment: Create a quick script called check.php containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then run it in the browser. Look at the value for Loaded Configuration File on the first page, make sure you are amending the correct ``php.ini` file

Comment: I think this will answer you question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184881/logs-php-error-but-not-display-it-in-browser

Comment: @RiggsFolly It reports `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` which is what I'm editing. EDIT: Technically the setting there has always been `display_errors = Off` and `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`.

Comment: @AmanSingh My reading of that is I've already done the suggested steps.  What are you thinking I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found the answer for whatever other poor soul is still stuck on CodeIgniter v2.  In `system/core/Common.php` there is a `_exception_handler()` function that has the following:

```
if (($severity & error_reporting()) == $severity)
{
    $_error->show_php_error($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
}
```

The above appears to be what's causing errors to be shown to publicly and while could't find CI v2 code on Github I did see it was removed (or possibly just moved) in V3:

[CodeIgniter V3 `_exception_handler`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/9b8f2b7a8405acd1b8ad5956ada3d84472b1e8ae/system/core/Common.php#L643-L669)

Here is the complete (v2.2.6) function (unmodified in any way as far as I know):

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
* Exception Handler
*
* This is the custom exception handler that is declaired at the top
* of Codeigniter.php.  The main reason we use this is to permit
* PHP errors to be logged in our own log files since the user may
* not have access to server logs. Since this function
* effectively intercepts PHP errors, however, we also need
* to display errors based on the current error_reporting level.
* We do that with the use of a PHP error template.
*
* @access   private
* @return   void
*/
if ( ! function_exists('_exception_handler'))
{
    function _exception_handler($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
    {
         // We don't bother with "strict" notices since they tend to fill up
         // the log file with excess information that isn't normally very helpful.
        if ($severity == E_STRICT)
        {
            return;
        }

        $_error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');

        // Should we display the error? We'll get the current error_reporting
        // level and add its bits with the severity bits to find out.
        if (($severity & error_reporting()) == $severity)
        {
            $_error->show_php_error($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
        }

        // Should we log the error?  No?  We're done...
        if (config_item('log_threshold') == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        $_error->log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had error notices on an old pyro site which just wouldn't go away no matter what! But this fixed it!